# MySQL: Find the average balance of customers based on State

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, average, aggregate-functions

Find the average balance of customers based on State

```
select * from Customer_info;
select * from Account_info;

select Customer_info.Customer_ID, Customer_info.State, Account_info.Balance, Account_info.Customer_ID
from Customer_info
inner join Account_info on Customer_info.Customer_ID = Account_info.Customer_ID;

select Customer_info.Customer_ID, Customer_info.State, avg(Balance) as Average_Bal
from Customer_info
inner join Account_info on Customer_info.Customer_ID = Account_info.Customer_ID
group by State;
```

Stuck, could use some help/suggestions.

Comment: Adding sample input/output to your question would help getting an answer here.

Comment: Take Customer_info.Customer_ID out of the select in the last query and that should give you what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
select c.state, avg(a.balance) as average_bal
from customer_info c
inner join account_info a on a.customer_id = c.customer_id
group by c.state;
```

The `select` clause needs to be consistent with the `group by` clause: all non-aggregated column must appear in the `group by` clause.

Note that I added table aliases, which shortens the query. I also prefixed column `balance` with the table it belongs to, so the query is unambiguous (I assumed `account_info`).